# Upgrading Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 4.3

Tags: java, hibernate

I am upgrading my application from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 4.3. I have used the  org.hibernate.util.PropertiesHelper in hibernate 3.

And while upgrading to hibernate 4, I unable to find the place where the org.hibernate.util. PropertiesHelper class moved in Hibernate4.

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you use `PropertiesHelper` for in particular in your legacy app?

Answer (score 4):

org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationHelper is most likely what you are looking for.  Notice its designation as 'internal' though